# How do I concatenate strings in MASM x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have spent the last 3 hours trying to do this program.

It is 32 bit.

I have looked around SO and read the book assigned to my class but I couldn't find good info on string concatenation for my case.

The StrCatAsm procedure keeps printing out ' Pat' to the output text file when it should print 'hello Pat'.

These asm functions are called from a C++ file.

string1Add contains `char str7[MAX_SIZE] = {'h','e','l','l','o',0,'@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@',0};`

and

string2Add contains `char str8[MAX_SIZE] = {' ','P','a','t',0,'@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@',0};`

This is the guild for programming this function that was given to the class:

```
    ;--------------------------------------------
;StrCatAsm - append  0 terminated string2 to  0 terminated string1
;   entry: str1Add contains the address of string1
;          str2Add contains the address of string2
;   exit:  NONE
;   note: StrCatAsm puts in terminating 0
;
;   example: char str1[] = {'h','e','l','l','o',0};
;            char str2[] = {'w','o','r','l','d',0};
;   after StrCatAsm(str1,str2) 
;            string1 = 'h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d',0
;
;  The above is how you would call StrCatAsm from C++.
;
;  To call StrCatAsm from another asm function use:
;
;   To call StrCatAsm from an asm function use:
;       
;       push str2Add ;address of string 2
;       push str1Add ;address of string 1
;       call StrCatAsm
;       ;no add esp, 8 needed because stack cleaup automatically done

;
; Do not use a loop in this function. 
; Do not call StrLenAsm in this function.

; StrCatAsm should zero terminate the concatenated string which is done by StrCpyAsm
; when you call it to copy str2 to the end of str1.
;
; Choose 2 instructions from the following string instructions to use:
; rep, repe, repne, movsb,stosb,cmpsb,scasb
;
;populate ecx with MAX_LEN defined at the top of this file
;get to the end of str1 using two string instructions
;then call StrCpyAsm to copy str2 to end of str1.
;
;   Note: the parameters below (str1Add and str2Add) contain the address of the 
;         strings you want to work with. To transfer those addesses to a register
;         just use mov reg, str1Add 
;         Do not use mov reg, offset str1Add and 
;         do not use lea reg, str1Add
```

Here is my work so far.
Max len is defined at the top of the file as: MAX_LEN EQU 0FFFFFFFFh

```
StrCatAsm PROC  uses eax edi ecx esi  ,  ;save registers used
                str1Add:DWORD,  ;address of string1
                str2Add:DWORD   ;address of string2

mov edi, str1Add
;mov esi, str2Add

;Student code here( you may change or delete any of the above 2 lines of code for efficiency if necessary)
;If you use the above 2 lines, you  must comment them
mov ecx, MAX_LEN                ;Move max len to ecx.
mov al, 'h'
cld 
repne scasb
jnz quit
dec edi

push str2Add                        ;address of string 2
push str1Add                    ;address of string 1
call StrCpyAsm                  ;Call StrCpyAsm to copy the strings together.

quit:
    ret                             ;return to caller

StrCatAsm ENDP
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. We have being doing all our programs in 32bit

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts.

Comment: @RossRidge My teacher asked me to remove this but the site wont let me.

Comment: @Aeryes Then it's best to contact moderators via a flag, explain the situation and ask for removal. You can't delete it by yourself because others invested their time with answers. It's also the reason why you shouldn't remove code from your question: doing so would invalidate their answer.

Comment: You're not allowed to delete or vandalize homework questions, even if your teacher asks you to. Despite Modus Tollens' comment it's likely that moderators will reject any flag asking for this question to be deleted.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
push str1Add                    ;address of string 1
```

should be

```
push edi                        ;address of string 1
```

because you want to push the pointer you modified not the original pointer you were passed

Comment: When I do that I get an access violation.

Comment: Nvm, it doesnt give me an access violation, it just prints hello now

Comment: Still just prints hello. I think im doing it all wrong. The guild saysI need to get to the end of the string using one 2 of the listed instructions before calling StrCpyAsm but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: @Aeryes: Did the code snippet change? I could have swarn that al was zero before. In cany case, al = 'h' won't work.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong here?

- In order to find out where the second string needs to attach itself to the first string, you need to scan the first string for its terminating zero. Your code presently erroneously scans for the 'h' character. This needs to become `mov al, 0`.
- The first argument to *StrCpyAsm* is not the start of the first string but rather the end (where you found that terminating zero). After the `repne scasb` instruction, `EDI-1` will be this address.

```
mov edi, str1Add   ; Address of START of string 1
mov ecx, MAX_LEN
mov al, 0
cld 
repne scasb
dec edi

push str2Add       ; Address of START of string 2
push edi           ; Address of END of string 1
call StrCpyAsm     ; Call StrCpyAsm to copy the strings together.
```

You don't need that `jnz quit` because with such a huge (0FFFFFFFFh) repetition count in the `ECX` register, it's next to impossible to not encounter a zero byte!

> Choose 2 instructions from the following string instructions to use:

Technically with `repne scasb`, you've chosen 1 **string instruction** and an accompanying **instruction prefix**. `repne` is not an instruction by itself.